# How to combine mutliple mouseenter event with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseenter

I am triing to make a multiple mouseenter into child element which add class for thoses elements.
But unfortunaltely it is not working...

Here the exemple with the code and what it is doing. http://js.do/Aleqxs/fonction_html

First mousenter transform my ligne "NOIR ET BLANC" into "ROUGE ET NOIR"
my second mousenter should transform "ROUGE" in RED color... but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a copy paste error in my opinion, you use

```
$(".change_into_red").mouseenter(function(){
 $(".this").addClass("red");
});
```

when it should be

```
$(".change_into_red").mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).addClass("red");
});
```

Moreover, when you are attempting to include this line of html

```
var code_avec_html = '<span class="change_into_red">ROUGE</span> ET NOIR';
```

in jQuery's html function like this

```
$(this).html(code_avec_html);
```

It will work to display that html, however, any events that were going to work on the class in that html will only work if they were *delegated*. Your current setup only assigns these events one time. In order to also have these events work for future elements, you need to use delegation with the `delegate` function.

```
$("body").delegate(".change_into_red", "mouseenter", function () {
 $(this).addClass("red");
});

$("body").delegate(".change_into_red", "mouseleave", function () {
 $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

Comment: ok I changed it. but still look at the following line in my exemple; It does not solve the probleme.

Comment: @user3532990 - See edits please. Dynamically created elements need events delegated to them.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It does work now. Never heard of delegate before. need to get updated I guess, I will inquire about delegate. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure :) Newer jQuery versions use `on` as opposed to delegate.

Comment: @travus_J OK do you mean that I should use "on" instead of "delegate"?

Comment: @user3532990 - `on` was not working in your demo page for whatever reason, so I used delegate because that did work when tested. Delegate and on are essentially the same, they just swap their first two arguments, on uses the event first, delegate uses the selector first.